# How to conclude that $ \bar r \equiv 0$ (mod $m$)?

Tags: formal-power-series, local-rings

Let $A$ be complete local ring with unique maximal ideal $m$.

Consider the equation $x^h-r=q(\gamma x^h)$, where $\gamma$ is a unit in $ A[[x]]$, $ r \in A[x]$ is a polynomial  and $q \in A[[x]]$.

We have to show that $ r \in m[x]$.

So reducing the equation over $m$, we have

$x^h-\bar r=\bar q(\gamma x^h) \Rightarrow x^h+\gamma \bar qx^h=\bar r.$

How to conclude that $ \bar r \equiv 0$ (mod $m$)?

Comment: Does $q(\gamma x^h)$ mean that the power series $\gamma \cdot x^h$ gets substituted into the power series $q$ (as in: if $q =\sum a_n x^n, \gamma=1$, then $q(x^h) = \sum a_n x^{hn}$)? But then is not $A = \mathbb Z_3, q=x, \gamma=2, r= -x^h$ a counterexample?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, No, here it is just a product of power series not composition. That is,  $q(\gamma x^h)$ is simply $q(x)*\gamma(x)*x^h$

Comment: Well, then $A= \mathbb Z_3, q=2, \gamma=1, r=-x^h$ is a counterexample.